# How to unset ENV variables that where set during runtime

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I created a custom Dockerfile, and it runs various scripts via a master script executed through

> CMD ["masterScript.sh"]

Now, after building that dockerfile, I run that image and pass some environment variables during runtime. Like so:

> $ docker run --env VAR1=value1 ...

My question is, how do I unset that VAR1? Clearly I can't do it inside the Dockerfile because that gets overridden.

And when I do an:

> unset VAR1

inside the master script, it doesn't seem to work. I know this because when I do an exec into my container the environment variable VAR1 is still there.

Is the a way to unset an ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE that was set during runtime?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute a script after the container loads that simply executes:

```
docker exec your-container-name sh -c "unset VAR1"
```